# Picture Filter Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, image

Okay, so, basically, I made this program that asks the user for a link to a picture, then asks the user for the type of filter they would like to use, and applies the filter to the picture

```
function start(){
    askForImage();
    askForFilter();
}

function askForImage(){
    var link = readLine("Please give the link to the image");
    println("Fitting the image to canvas as best a possible.");
    var image = new WebImage(link);
    image.setPosition(0, 0);
    image.setSize(getWidth(), getHeight());
    add(image);
}

function askForFilter(){
    var filterType = readLine("What filter would you like to use on your photo?");

    if(filterType == "darken"){
        setTimeout(function(){
        darkenFilter(image);
        }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
    }else if(filterType == "brighten"){
        setTimeout(function(){
        brightenFilter(image);
         }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
    }else if(filterType == "invert"){
        setTimeout(function(){
        invert(image);
        }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
    }else if(filterType == "grayscale"){
        setTimeout(function(){
        blackAndWhiteFilter(image);
        }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
    }else if(filterType == "remove blue"){
        setTimeout(function(){
        removeBlue(image);
        }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
    }else if(filterType == "remove red"){
        setTimeout(function(){
        removeRed(image);
        }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
    }else if(filterType == "remove green"){
        setTimeout(function(){
        removeGreen(image);
        }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
    }else if(filterType == "saturate"){
        setTimeout(function(){
        saturate(image);
        }, IMAGE_LOAD_WAIT_TIME);
    }else{
        println("That is not a possible filter option.");
    }
}
```

(Sorry, I shortened the code as much as possible to get the point across)
This is the section I seem to be having trouble with. I left out all the functions that filter the image itself because I know that the filters work, I tested them. The apparent issue seems to be that the filters are taking the image the wrong way. I tried using a constant URL as the image, and that worked fine, but when the user is the one who enters the URL, the filter doesn't work. I think that the program may be running the filters **before** the picture loads, but I wouldn't know how to fix that even if it was the problem. I'd really appreciate the help in troubleshooting my code, thanks!

---[This](https://codehs.com/share/uUkewVv8aGlIgXPOtlLF) is a link to the code mentioned---

Comment: Is loading image via PHP a possible option for your app? Or else change logic to _"user uploads from hard drive"_ instead of current _"uploads via link"_

Answer (score 1):

What you're running into is a security limitation of the web platform.

Drawing a cross-origin image (roughly speaking, any image loaded from another domain) onto a HTML canvas "taints" the canvas. This prevents any function from being used that reads information back from the canvas, such as `getPixel`.

For more information, see the MDN article [CORS enabled image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image). However, you will probably need to have the user upload a local image file (using a file input), rather than specifying one by URL.

Comment: But, as I believe I mentioned in the question; I have used the filters with the link in a constant variable, so it should work the same using a `readLine`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Depends on where the link pointed. If it was to an image on the same domain, that would be a same-origin image, and wouldn't be subject to cross-origin restrictions.

Comment: The link that I used for the constant, and for the input were both the same.